# route:cache still not working with cleared api/routes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running an API however `php artisan route:cache` still won't refresh without giving this error message

```
 LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at /var/www/html/kmobile/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919| 
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921|
```

routes/api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

For reference, I've already did do `composer dumpautoload` and other clear commands but still to no avail.

Comment: Please share your action method and route

Comment: there is route without closure e.g `Route::get('test', function() { return true; });` check all your routes

Comment: @A.ANoman already shared api.php. I've used terminal to do my action

Comment: @AlzafanChristian yep checked 4 of them, none has that closure function. Tried re-running ```route:cache``` still refers back to the middleware call even though I've deleted it

Comment: @iamlux20 actually, youve only shared the first line of api.php thats just a `use` statement. Thats not really helpful, we need to see the actual route declarations from that file.

Comment: or use `php artisan route:list` and check if there is any Closure in action column

Comment: @AlzafanChristian it still shows the middleware closure action for some reason even thought it's deleted

Comment: please take a look https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22034